# Bad Request (400) error while trying to access REST API using requests in python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

This error is so common that I found several hits on this error. However, couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I am trying to consume a REST API (not one of the publicly available ones) using requests module in Python. However, the specifications for the API consumption indicates that I call a POST method with URI, `Content-type = 'application/xml'` and body `"<authCommand><userID> </userID><password> </password></authCommand>"`.

I tried this in the Python using requests: 
`r1 = requests.post('https://abc.360.net/rest/auth/1/login.xml',data= None, auth=('sdm@company.com','*********'), headers = {'content-type':'application/xml'})`

When I run this, I receive a bad request error.

Is this the correct approach? Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API documentation? It is likely that you are not properly following the API's requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auth` argument is to set `Authorization` *header*  (basic http authentication by default). The API expects credentials in the *body*:

```
r = request.post(url, data=xml, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
```

where `xml=b"<authCommand><userID>sdm@company.com</authCommand>..."`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. This worked. Its the exact syntax I was looking for. I was not sure how to give the body in post method. Thanks again.